# WHERE not working with INNER JOIN in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

When I run:

```
SELECT * from actor inner join film_actor fa ON actor.actor_id = fa.actor_id
```

I get results.

But running:

```
SELECT * from actor inner join film_actor fa WHERE actor.actor_id = fa.actor_id
```

It gives error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"

As far as I understand, WHERE is correct usage in this case.

Any input would help.

Comment: . . Your understanding is wrong.  `ON` is the correct syntax.

Comment: The old-fashioned way to join two tables was `FROM table_a, table_b WHERE table_a.bid = table_b.id`. That format didn't use keyword `JOIN`. 
Forget that syntax, it's obsolete. Use `JOIN...USING...` (I prefer this whenever possible) or `JOIN...ON...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand, WHERE is correct usage in this case.

No, you mis-understood this.

The WHERE clause comes **after** all JOIN clauses, it can never be part of the JOIN *condition*.

The general format of a JOIN is:

```
table_b JOIN table_b ON <some_condition>
```

there is no `WHERE` allowed in that part. The only variation to that are different types of joins (`left join`, `full join`, `right join`). The joins always follow the FROM clause. Only if all joins are fully specified (**including** the join condition using `ON`) you can start writing the `WHERE` clause.

Ignoring sub-queries and derived tables for the moment, you can imagine the `FROM` clause as "one big thing", and only if that is complete you not allowed to write the `WHERE` clause.

Maybe you are thinking of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins:

```
SELECT * 
from actor, 
     film_actor fa 
WHERE actor.actor_id = fa.actor_id
```

But using the explicit `JOIN` operator with the join condition in the `ON` clause is much better coding style. Don't get used to the outdated and ancient implicit joins.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit about 'The WHERE clause comes after all JOIN clauses, it can never be part of the JOIN condition'. In my case I too have placed WHERE after INNER JOIN clause.

Comment: @Mandroid An `INNER JOIN` [**requires** a join clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) of either `NATURAL`, `ON <condition>` or `USING <columns>`

Comment: @Mandroid: see my edit, I hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . `JOIN` is not really a "clause".  It is an operator in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

For that style of syntax you want

```
SELECT * from actor, film_actor fa WHERE actor.actor_id = fa.actor_id
```

Comment: But nobody should use this syntax `:-)` ... it has been deprecated for nearly 30 years.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it hasn't bee deprecated, only superseded. It's still 100% valid standard SQL. But I do agree that no one should use it any more.